# Is it possible to generate strict type from partial type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

We can generate partial type from strict type like below (from TypeScript 2.1):

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
type Person = { name: string, age: number } 
type PersonPartial = Partial<Person>; // === { name?: string, age?: number }
```

Conversely, Is it possible to generate strict type from partial type ?

```
type Strict<T> = { ??? };

type Person = { name: string; age?: number; }
type PersonStrict = Strict<Person>; // === { name: string, age: number }
```

**What I actually want**

I need below 2 types, but don't want to write them twice.

```
type Person = { name: string, age?: number, /* and other props */ }
type PersonStrict = { name: string, age: number, /* and other props */ }
```

I found a verbose solution like below, but I want to know there is a better way or not.

```
type RequiredProps = { name: string, /* and other required props */ };
type OptionalProps = { age: number, /* and other optional props */ };
type Person = RequiredProps & Partial<OptionalProps>;
type PersonStrict = RequiredProps & OptionalProps;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Required](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1359) type.

```
type Person = { name: string; age?: number; }
type RequiredPerson = Required<Person>; // === { name: string, age: number }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do this.

```
type Person = { name: string, age?: number };
type Strict<T> = { [K in (keyof T)]: T[K] };
type PersonStrict = Strict<Person>;
```

**Parentheses attached to `keyof T` are mandatory.**

Without these parentheses, `age` is still optional.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is unintentional behaviour, and will be fixed. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12791